# Google spreadsheet, passing parameter

Tags: google-sheets

Okay, I'm an huge noob with that kind of stuff, and I don't really know where to begin with. Google help is somehow not enough :/.
I want to make a conditionnal count on a single column :

```
COUNTIF(A1:A10, "3")
```

It will return the number of 3 in the cells from A1 to A10. Now the problem is, there can be multiples values in each cell formatted like this : "1; 3; 5". I can easily match this using regex :

```
B1 = REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"3")
```

Then repeat and sum on the second column. Now, how can I do this using a single formula?

```
COUNTIF(A1:A10, REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A10,"3"))
```

This doesn't work because regexextract take as an input a single cell. I would like to tell it to use the same cell than in the countif, but I have no clue on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can have regextract working on an array. E.g.:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(--regexmatch(A2:A&"", "3")))
```

should count all threes (either single or in cells with multiple values), but in case you have multiple threes in one cell, you may need to use something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sum(len(A:A)-len(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"3","")))/len("3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=COUNTIF(SPLIT(JOIN(";",A:A),";"),"3")
```